# datetime converting format in python

Tags: python-3.x

have list of an other lists that contains date (y,m,d h,m,s,ms), and an other list of some values. I would plot this values in function of date but I couldn't convert the first list on date. How can I do this?

```
import datetime
import matplotlib
from time import mktime
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime



date = [
['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.400'], 
['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.500'], 
['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.600']
]
values = [2,4,5]
for i in range(len(date)):
   date[i][0] = eval(date[i][0])
   date[i][1] = eval(date[i][1])
   date[i][2] = date[i][2].strip()



date = [' '.join(elem) for elem in date]

 >>>['2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.400', '2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.500', '2017/10/27 
 08:18:12 0.600']

 date = [mktime(datetime.strptime(elem,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 
  0.%f').timetuple()) for elem in date]

 >>ValueError: time data '2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.400' does not match format 
  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0.%f
```

I have lists of thousands of lines so if some could this more efficiently I'll be very grateful. thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?  We're happy helping with problems, but we're not a codewriting service...

Comment: Hi, this is what I did

Comment: 'import datetime
import matplotlib
from time import mktime
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime'

Comment: date = [
    ['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.400'], 
    ['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.500'], 
    ['"2017/10/27"', '"08:18:12"', '       0.600']
]
values = [2,4,5]

for i in range(len(date)):
    date[i][0] = eval(date[i][0])
    date[i][1] = eval(date[i][1])
    date[i][2] = date[i][2].strip()



date = [' '.join(elem) for elem in date]

>>>['2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.400', '2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.500', '2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.600']

date = [mktime(datetime.strptime(elem,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0.%f').timetuple()) for elem in date]

Comment: and I get this error : >>ValueError: time data '2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.400' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0.%f' '

Comment: Can you please post that as part of the question?

Comment: @roelofs could please check what i did. thank you.

Comment: Just posted an answer.  Let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message actually tells you exactly what's wrong :)  The python function you're using, does pattern matching to find the different elements (minutes, hours, etc) in your time string.

You're using:

```
date = [mktime(datetime.strptime(elem,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 0.%f').timetuple()) for elem in date]
```

but your time string is `'2017/10/27 08:18:12 0.400'`.  You're using `/` and not `-` as a separator, so the function above can't find a matching string.  Change your code above to:

```
date = [mktime(datetime.strptime(elem,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S 0.%f').timetuple()) for elem in date]
```